# Can't find Ramexal SSD on Lenovo IdeaPad 1 11ADA05

Tags: linux, system-installation, ssd, sd-card

I am trying to install Linux on my Lenovo IdeaPad 1 11ADA05. I have prepared the installer on an SD card. It boots into the SD card fine, but when I try to install the distro, it can't find my SSD. My SSD model is an eMMC card 64gb Ramexal SSD. I have tried multiple different distros, including Arch, Manjaro, Ubuntu, Mint, Kubuntu, and GNU Guix. Here's the output of `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 81.81 MiB, 85786624 bytes, 167552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 537.95 MiB, 564084736 bytes, 1101728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 1.31 GiB, 1404850176 bytes, 2743848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 656.67 MiB, 688570368 bytes, 1344864 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 29.72 GiB, 31914983424 bytes, 62333952 sectors
Disk model: MassStorageClass
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         64 5496075 5496012  2.6G  0 Empty
/dev/sda2       5496076 5504267    8192    4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

Is there any way to get my SSD to work or am I stuck on Windows?

Comment: There definitely is a way to make it work, running Linux off of an eMMC card is fairly commonplace for a long time. Looks like something is going wrong on your machine, perhaps a missing kernel module or a bug. Can you please look into the kernel log (`dmesg`) and post anything relevant? (Perhaps `dmesg | grep -i mmc` would be a good start.) Try also `modinfo mmc_block` and `lsmod | grep mmc` and tell us if you get any output.

Comment: dmesg | grep -i mmc results in nothing related to mmc cards.

Comment: @TooTea mmc_block appears to exist according to modinfo, but lsmod | grep mmc doesn't output anything

Comment: \@TooTea My cpu is AMD 3020e if that makes a difference

Comment: Hmm, can you paste the full `dmesg` output (perhaps to your favourite paste service) and `lspci` as well?

Comment: @TooTea Sure, here's the link: https://pastebin.com/X16Mw1dP

Comment: @TooTea The processor isn't Ryzen, it's 3020e

Comment: Fixed (your CPU should still have a builtin eMMC, just like the rest of the Zen-based parts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the recent Ubuntu Mainline Kernel 5.13 I can now see the mmc device on my IdeaPad 1 11ADA05.

Comment: I successfully installed Manjaro after building a 5.13 iso!

Answer (score 1):

**Disabling the IOMMU might help.**

Looking at the output from `lspci`, it's obvious that there's no PCI device there that would correspond to a SD/MMC host controller. This explains why the mmc driver modules are never loaded (loading the modules is triggered when a matching device appears).

I've never seen that particular machine, so I don't know for sure what kind of a MMC controller it uses. However, it's fairly likely that the absence of a dedicated controller means the memory is wired up to the built-in controller in the CPU.

Given that its PCI device is also nowhere to be seen, I suspect you are affected by a variant of the bug mentioned on the kernel mailing list a while ago:

https://www.lkml.org/lkml/2019/9/21/31 "IOMMU vs Ryzen embedded EMMC controller"

In short, due to a misconfiguration of the platform ACPI tables (provided by the vendor of the machine), the IOMMU (marketed as "AMD-Vi" or "Intel VT-d") does not have a proper mapping for the PCI device and thereby hides it from the kernel.

To see if this is the case, try looking around in the UEFI setup for a toggle option that would let you disable the IOMMU. If disabling the IOMMU helps, you can leave it off unless you want to run any virtual machines on the device and give those VMs fast access to the HW (typically used for accelerated GPU rendering in VMs).

As an alternative test, you can try loading the driver by hand using `modprobe sdhci_acpi` and see if you get any errors from the IOMMU in the `dmesg` log.

If disabling the IOMMU helps but you'd really like to keep it enabled, you'll need a workaround using `ivrs_acpihid` along the lines of https://www.lkml.org/lkml/2019/10/9/1015 :

> I suspect that there is something missing in the IVRS table, where it needs
> to provide ACPI HID for the eMMC device.
>
> See kernel parameter:

```
ivrs_acpihid    [HW,X86_64]
                         Provide an override to the ACPI-HID:UID<->DEVICE-ID
                         mapping provided in the IVRS ACPI table. For
                         example, to map UART-HID:UID AMD0020:0 to
                         PCI device 00:14.5 write the parameter as:
                                 ivrs_acpihid[00:14.5]=AMD0020:0
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer, but I can't actually find that option. Is there a backup plan? Is AMD SVM related?

Comment: I get no errors from sudo modprobe sdhci_acpi

Comment: You can also boot with the `amd_iommu=off` kernel parameter instead, which should give you more or less the same result as disabling it in the firmware.

Comment: That didn't help.

Comment: Despite the answer not working, it does give me hope that 5.12 will address this issue. Thanks!